# Creating JS objects in PHP with commas in between

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to create an array of JS objects from a PHP array, but I'm struggling to find a way to insert commas in between each object.

Here's what I'm trying to output:

```
var things = [
    {
        a: "foo",
        b: "bar"
    },  // Comma on this line
    {
        a: "moo",
        b: "car"
    }   // No comma on this line
];
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
var things = [
    <?php foreach ($things as $thing): ?>
    {
        a: "<?php echo $thing->getA(); ?>",
        b: "<?php echo $thing->getB(); ?>"
    }
    <?php endforeach; ?>
];
```

I suppose I could resort to something ugly, like an `if` statement that only runs once:

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    if ($i == 1) {
        echo '{';
        $i++;
    } else {
        echo ',{';
    }
?>
```

Is there not a cleaner/better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like...

```
$JSONData = json_encode($YourObject);
```

There's also a decode...

```
$OriginalObject = json_decode($JSONData);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PHP array and want something usable in JavaScript, you can use `json_encode()`

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

The above example will output:
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

Answer (score 0):

Create the desired structure as PHP Arrays and then use json_encode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
$plainThing = array();

foreach ($things as $thing) {
    $plainThing[] = array('a' => $thing.getA(), 'b' => $thing.getB());
}

echo json_encode($plainThing);
```